# Textview scroll on Imageview like Pulse app scroll

Tags: android

In my application I want to scroll the text on Image view like Pulse application,Need not scroll inside the text view. Please give the solution for this.[image]

![enter image description here][2]

[image]

Comment: see changes to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use a framelayout and inside of it place first imageview and then textview or a layoutview with bachground and a textview inside of it

Comment: Imageview is top of the layout(Not background of layout) and the textview is below that imageview, now I want to scroll the textview over the imageview like above picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  may be helpful :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

You can try this
Add margin to textview

```
 android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
```

And make background image as it is here.

Comment: You answer for scroll the text on imageview, but I am asking like pulse app, that is, Imageview is top of the layout(Not background of layout) and the textview is below that imageview, now I want to scroll the textview over the imageview like above picture.

Comment: @Maheswaran see changes to my answer.