# How to scroll a textview on imageview like google play

Tags: android

i'm trying to make a newsfeed which has a textview on bottom and an imageview on the top. The text should be scrolled on the imageview exactly like google play when you scroll the descriptions of app on their banner.

I have found 2 topics here which ask exactly my question but unfortunately without a correct answer 
[Textview scroll on Imageview like Pulse app scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717445/textview-scroll-on-imageview-like-pulse-app-scroll)

[Textview Scrolling Behind the Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741869/textview-scrolling-behind-the-imageview)

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    />
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding_top="200dp"
            >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Set the Padding_top of an linearlayout to the height of an imageView(do this in java or set some random number like I have done). Hope this will work.

Comment: On behalf of @RTN073:  the above solution did not work for me as expected. Would you please provide corresponding java class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:text="@string/blablabla" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```